# python oracle bulk insert throws error

Tags: python, django, oracle

I am getting the following error 
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'
when doing bulk insert in oracle db.

**Code** Snippet:

```
(528, 'TEST', 'TEST', 1)
from django.db import connection
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.prepare("INSERT INTO c_dim_value(id, c_dimension_id, display_value, code, active_code) VALUES (c_dim_value_seq.nextval, :1, :2, :3, :4)")

        cursor.executemany(None, new_dim_value_to_inserted)
```

> Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ends with'

Comment: Can you give the traceback from python?